# Get all values for radio buttons using jquery on a page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have 4 questions with two radio buttons each. User must check yes or no for each question.

Users must answer Yes in all questions to be able to proceed with the app. 
With the jquery code below, if the user answers only 2 questions, only 2 answers is reported in tempArray variable.

I want to be able to see all the 4 answers whether answered or not answered in tempArray. I will then be able to loop through the array and determine 
the answers that are null or No

Example
Answered All
1.Yes
2.Yes
3.Yes
4.Yes

Did Not answer all
1. Yes
2. Null
3. Null
4. No

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    

            $('#Continue').click(function () {

                var $RButtons = $('input[type="radio"]');
                var tempArray = new Array();

                var i = 0;
                jQuery.each($RButtons, function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var value = $(this).attr('value');
                        tempArray[i] = value;
                        i++;
                    }
                });

            })

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to skip by two.

```
    var $rb = $('input:radio')
    var tempArray = new Array();
    var questionNo = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $rb.length; i += 2) {
      tempArray[questionNo] = "Question " + (questionNo + 1) + " is ";
      if ($($rb[i]).is(':checked')) {            
        tempArray[questionNo] += $($rb[i]).attr('value');
      }
      else if ($($rb[i + 1]).is(':checked')) {
        tempArray[questionNo] += $($rb[i + 1]).attr('value');
      }
      else {
        tempArray[questionNo] += " is null";
      }
      questionNo++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the skip by two and the if statements? It works very well.

Comment: Because for each question you should have two radios.  So for each pair, if anyone is checked, take the value of it otherwise it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't testet this, but I see some problems with your code:

```
        $('#Continue').click(function () {

            var $RButtons = $('input[type="radio"]');
            var tempArray = new Array();

            var value;
            jQuery.each($RButtons, function () {
                if ($this.prop('checked', true)) { // jQuery 1.6+
                    value = $(this).val();
                    tempArray.push(value);
                }
            });
        })
```

1. You can use `$this.prop("checked", true)` to check if the radio button is checked or not (jQuery 1.6+)
2. You should simple use `$(this).val()` to determine value of checkbox.
3. You do not have to use a counter in your look, just use `.push`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
$('#Continue').click(function () {
              $('div').empty();
                var tempArray = new Array();
                     for ( var i=1; i <= 4; i++)
                     {    
                         var name = "q" + i;
                         var answered = false;
                         $('input:radio[name="' + name + '"]').each(function () {                                  
                          if(!answered)
                          {
                              if($(this).is(":checked"))
                              {
                                  tempArray.push("Question : "  + i + ", Answer : " +  $(this).attr("value"));
                                  answered = true;                                 
                              }                              
                          }
                         });
                         if(!answered)   
                              tempArray.push("Question : "  + i + ", Answer : Null ");
                     }


    $.each(tempArray,function(i)
                 {
                     $('div').append(tempArray[i] + "<br/>");
                 });



            });
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/86829ryz/17/